# Which distributions preserve its family after linear transformation?

Tags: random-variable

For example, if $X$ obeys a multivariate gaussian distribution and let $Y = AX + B$ where $A$ is the matrix for the transformation and $B$ a constant vector. Then $Y$ still obeys a gaussian distribution. Are there any other distributions that share this property?

Answer (score 4):

Yes them exists. *Elliptical distributions* share this property. *Gaussian* is a special case.

More formally, if a random vector $X$ have an elliptical distribution $El (\mu, \Sigma, \phi)$  then any linear combination of that, $Y = AX + B$, maintain an elliptical distribution with the same characteristic generator. More precisely:

$Y$ follow the distribution $El (A\mu +B, A\Sigma A’, \phi)$

Where: $\mu$ stand for *location vector*; $\Sigma$ for *scale matrix* and $\phi$ for *characteristic generator*.

*Elliptical* is a *family* of distributions. In the notable example of multivariate *t-distribution*, $\phi$ stand for *degree of freedom* (shared among all marginals). If $\phi$ go to infinity we come back to the *Normal* distribution case invoked in the question.

As reference I suggest: *Quantitative Risk Management: Concepts, Techniques and Tools* – McNeil, Frey and  Embrechts; Princeton University Press 2005 (pag 95).

Comment: Why downvote? I can document what I have affirmed.

Comment: This property is very relevant in portfolio theory, then elliptical distributions are. Moreover this property imply that the Central Limit Theorem are not applicable everywhere.

Comment: My answer was correct also before, however I detailed it now.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm studying about the theory of extreme value and there is the Generalized extreme value distribution (GEV) which preserve its family after linear transformation (which includes Gumbel, Weibull and Frechet). But the constant $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ depend on $n$